# How to implement callback REST service for Android sync task?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, rest

I am trying to implement a 2-ways sync mechanism between my android app and Google App Engine (GAE). I plan to send a JSON dump with all the modified data from the android to the server. Then the server should reply with data changes that happened on the server side by sending a message to the device. This message needs to be handled in the callback on the device side. Here is where I am having troubles. Does anyone know of a possible solution I could use in order to do that?

Comment: do you wish to know when server is sending data to you?

Comment: that would be great to avoid polling all the time.

Comment: Then go for push notification. see android GCM

Comment: GCM is a good solution for push notifications, but I am afraid I need something different to implement the callback mechanism. Any ideas?